# Hyperledger fabric creating too many files in one directory

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, nfs, peer

Our deployment of hyperledger fabric is on 1.1 and the chain height is more then 10 Million. Now we have observed that if the peer crashes in order to get it up again it takes a lot of time  even more then 2 hours. On closer observation we have found that "ledgersData/chains/index/" has around more then 5000+ files. Even doing a simple ls takes a lot of time.

Is that the reason for the slowness of the peer while waking up? 
Has somebody else encountered similar problem as well?
Is there a way or configuration setting so that the files are generated in different folder for the "indexes"

The files are stored on a GPFS based NFS.

Any pointers in the right directions are appreciated.